# C++ Void Call Timeout

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, timeout

I`ve got a problem with my C++ application on a Raspberry Pi. This script should print a distance in cm one time before terminatig. But it should also check if the ultrasonic sensor is connected and if not the script should break. How could I do that? Is there a way to set a timeout for the getCM() method or has anyone another idea to solve this?
This is the code:

```
...

void setup() {
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(TRIG_R, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ECHO_R, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(TRIG_F, LOW);
    delay(30);
}

int getCM() {

    digitalWrite(TRIG_R, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(20);
    digitalWrite(TRIG_R, LOW);

    //Wait for echo start
    while(digitalRead(ECHO_R) == LOW);

    //Wait for echo end
    long startTime = micros();
    while(digitalRead(ECHO_R) == HIGH);
    long travelTime = micros() - startTime;

    int distance = travelTime / 58;

    return distance;
}
int main(void) {

    setup();

    printf("Distance: %dcm\n", getCM());

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Comment: I wish persons would stop calling C++ programs "scripts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking in advance for the ultrasonic sensor there's not much anyone can suggest without knowing more about the sensor. If the communication is purely bit-toggling you probably can't tell without more hardware.

For the second part, timing out `getCM`, add an extra condition to the `digitalRead` loops to force an exit. For example:

```
int timeout = <read timeout goes here>;
while((digitalRead(ECHO_R) == LOW)&&(--timeout));
if (!timeout)
{
    return -1; // Should never be able to read less than blanking distance 
               // from an ultrasonic sensor. -1 is certainly out of range.
}
```

In `main` you can either print out the -1 or check for -1 and print out a better error message. For more clarity, the second loop could `return -2;` on failure so you know what failed.